# CSS design un-even?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-4

Alright, I'm launching this website (beta) in an hour but I've just noticed an ugly bug. I've added a new counter (1, 2, 3, etc..) was previously using `<ol>`.

Look at this picture the before:
[image: Site preview]

everything was even, the vote up button, the text all the way down.

Now the live version after adding new counter: [www.leapfm.com](http://www.leapfm.com) is un even. (when it becomes double digits)

Please use FireBug or Chrome Developer Tools, if you need any further code I will provide it ASAP.

original code:

```
.subtext1 {
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 7pt;
color: #828282;


}

.song {
    height: 42px;
}
.counter {
float: left;
margin-right: 2px;
font-size: 14px;


}
.subtext {
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 7pt;
color: #828282;

}

.title {
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 10.3pt;
color: #828282;

}
```

Comment: I presume once you have your answer, you're going to fix the problem -- making the link to your site useless as an example.  Please include enough code in the question itself so that someone can reproduce the issue independently.

Comment: good point, will update initial post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm adding an answer because I can't preview my code with a comment and they're not giving me enough space.)
Yes, an ol (or table) would've worked. But a quick-fix solution would be to give the counter a fixed width (say 30px). The only problem with this would be if you started having a lot more digits.

If you wanted to fix this using JavaScript (which would work forever), use code like this (jQuery).

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var counters = $(".counter");
      var counterLen = counters.length; //one based
                                 //convert to zero based
      var largestWidth = counters[counterLen - 1].offsetWidth + "px";

      //WAY ONE: DO IT WITH A STYLESHEET (I recommend this)

      var stylesheetDiv = $("<div>");
      stylesheetDiv.html("<style type=\"text/css\">.counter{width: " + largestWidth + "}</style>");

      $("head").append(stylesheetDiv);

      //WAY TWO: DO IT WITH A JQUERY LOOP
      counters.css({width: largestWidth});
 </script>
```

I used way one before. I'm pretty sure I have to do the div with a stylesheet inside for IE8.

Answer (score 1):

- For `.subtext1`, give it a `margin-left: 15px`.
- For `.counter`, give it a height of `100%` or `22px`.
- And delete the multiple `&nbsp;` between `.title` and `.subtext1`.

Comment: pushing code to www.leapfm.com, that solved the (likes) line but if you look at the vote up arrow that is still off when it gets into double digits.

Comment: Do you want all the vote up arrows to be lined up vertically?

Comment: ah, one thing I notice now is.. if you go to www.leapfm.com and then click 'New songs' the .subtext1 is to far to the left. Is there anyway to make it more dynamic? so on that it always lines up with the title? hmm

Comment: Take the margin-left off of .subtext1 for that page. Only make a style tag for that page, because if you change the style in the master stylesheet, it'll mess up the home page.

It's not dynamic, but it'll do the job.